# add a field in using fields Grails plugin

Tags: grails, grails-3.3

I'm using `Grails 3.3.11` for developing an application, as the views were automatically generated using `fields plugin`, I was wondering how to add to the view a field not in the domain class , for example in the user registration view I want to add `confirm password` field , I reviewed the plugin documentation but I can't find anything may help me.

Answer (score 0):

The view is not limited to only include properties on the domain class.  You can render whatever you like the view, even if you are using scaffolding.  You can generate the views and edit them to include whatever you like.

Comment: There isn't really a tutorial because I think all you are talking about doing is putting an input field on a form.